# Javascript time difference via timepicker

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web timesheet where users use timepicker to determine start & end times and I'd like to have the form automatically find the difference between the two times and place it in a 3rd input box. I understand that I need to get the values, convert them to milliseconds, then subtract the first number from the second, convert the difference back to human time and display that in the third box. But I can't seem to wrap my head around time conversion in javascript. Here's what I have so far:

```
function date1math(){

var date1in = document.getElementById("date-1-in").value;
var date1out = document.getElementById("date-1-out").value;

date1in = date1in.split(":");
date1out = date1out.split(":");
var date1inDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, date1in[0], date1in[1], 0);
var date1outDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, date1out[0], date1out[1], 0);
var date1math = date1outDate.getTime() - date1inDate.getTime();
var hours = Math.floor(date1math / 1000 / 60 / 60);
date1math -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(date1math / 1000 / 60);

return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;

document.getElementById("date-1-subtotal").value = date1math(date1in, date1out);
}
```

I want to take the timepicker result (say 9:00am) from the input date-1-in, the timepicker result (say 5:00pm) from the input date-1-out, and then place the difference as a number in date-1-subtotal.

Comment: if you pass a new Date(date2-date1), you can then use getHours(), getMonth(), etc from the new Date to determine the contained datepart diffs, up to one year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the input is a string in the format hh:mm (e.g. 09:54) and that the two strings represent a time on the same day. You don't mention whether an am/pm suffix is included, but it's there in the text so I'll assume it might be.

If daylight saving changes can be ignored, the simplest method is to convert the string to minutes, find the difference, then convert back to hours and minutes, e.g.:

```
// Convert hh:mm[am/pm] to minutes
function timeStringToMins(s) {
  s = s.split(':');
  s[0] = /m$/i.test(s[1]) && s[0] == 12? 0 : s[0];
  return s[0]*60 + parseInt(s[1]) + (/pm$/i.test(s[1])? 720 : 0);
}

// Return difference between two times in hh:mm[am/pm] format as hh:mm
function getTimeDifference(t0, t1) {

  // Small helper function to padd single digits
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}

  // Get difference in minutes
  var diff = timeStringToMins(t1) - timeStringToMins(t0);

  // Format difference as hh:mm and return
  return   z(diff/60 | 0) + ':' + z(diff % 60); 
}

var t0 = '09:15am';
var t1 = '05:00pm';

console.log(getTimeDifference('09:15am', '05:00pm')); // 07:45
console.log(getTimeDifference('09:15', '17:00'));     // 07:45
```

If daylight saving is to be incorporated, you'll need to include the date so that date objects can be created and used for the time difference. The above can use either 12 or 24 hr time format.

Comment: Thanks, this did it - I was even able to isolate the functionality so that I can repeat it multiple times on a page and only call the variables for each action. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @RobG I've run into a problem with using 12 or 12:30, am or pm, they seem to mess it up. Is there a line I can add to the timeStringToMins(s) to convert '12' to '0'? I tried "if (s[0].value == '12') {s[0].value == '0';}" but that doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind I got it by adding "if (s[0] == '12') {s[0] = '0';}" to the timeStringToMins function

Comment: @JasonBoyce—you can to that, but it will break handling 24hr time. See updated function, which adjusts 12 hrs only where am/pm is used.